# Adding .pfx certificate to HttpWebRequest fails from Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

I have created a Asp.net web application-C#, where I need to send a HttpWebRequest with a .pfx certificate.

I have installed the certificate to the personal certificates folder(added rights for user NETWORK SERVICE) and able to see it in the X509Certificate2Collection and no issues while adding the certificate to the HttpWebRequest.

But it throws cannot connect to server error while fetching the response (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()

I am facing this issue only from web application, the same code works fine(got the correct response) when i tried using a C# console application.

```
            X509Store oLocalMachineStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            X509Certificate2Collection oCertColl;
            X509Certificate oCert = new X509Certificate();
            oLocalMachineStore.Open(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            oCertColl = oLocalMachineStore.Certificates.Find(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "mycertificate issuer", false);
            oLocalMachineStore.Close();
            foreach (X509Certificate oCertFromStore in oCertColl)
            {
                if (oCertFromStore.Issuer.Contains("mycertificate issuer"))
                {
                    oCert = oCertFromStore;
                    oCert.Import(@"certlocation\mycertificate.pfx", "pwd", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
                    break;
                }
            }

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("destination URL");
            req.ClientCertificates.Add(oCert);

            req.UserAgent = "LOL API Client";
            req.Accept = "application/json";
            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

            string result = null;
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: What do you see in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: I have changed the application pool identity to NetworkService and added full control over the certificate for NetworkService.

Comment: Why are you re-importing in the loop? Import once and always use them?

Comment: i couldn't find any request related to the path i have tried.

Comment: Why are you re-importing in the loop? Import once and always use them?- i have tried that way also.
but the result was same. i am wondering how the code works from a console app and fails from a web app..!!!

Comment: the error message i am getting is 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: When trying HttpWebRequest from web application i couldn't find any entry related to the path i have tried.

When i tried the URL directly from fiddler after copying the pfx to the fiddler certificate location it worked.

Answer (score -1):

The issue got resolved after adding proxy to the http request.

```
req.Proxy = New Net.WebProxy("ProxyURL", False);
```

But still i have no idea, how it worked when i tried with the same code from a console application with out adding proxy.

If anyone has any idea on this please share.